# String Assertion/Throwing Exception in Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, exception, assertion

bat file via Jenkins. I have a part of code which looks as below

```
IF %Status% == Completed (
    Echo Process has executed successfully
)

ELSE (
    <Code to be added>
)
```

My requirement is that if Status has a value other than 'Completed' then the bat file must throw an exception or something so that the Jenkins Build Fails. Is there any way of assertions or throwing exceptions in bat files? Please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Each line of a batch file is seen as a new command. `Else` on its own is not, so as it is on a new line, it is seen as one. You need to put the parenthesis on the same line as `else`.

Additionally, you need to double quote your matches to ensure you eliminate any possible whitespace. I have added `/i` switch to the `if` statement to make the match case insensitive.

```
IF /i "%Status%" == "Completed" (
    echo Process has executed successfully
) else (
    echo Failed to build
    pause
    exit /b 1
)
```

A different way is to not use else.

```
IF not /i "%Status%" == "Completed" goto :error
echo Process has executed successfully
echo other success code goes here
goto :eof
:error
echo Your code has failed.
pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks but how to throw some custom exception inside else

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: I will trigger this code via Jenkins. So if the code goes to else block I want my bulid to fail

Comment: If you simply want to stop the script and then exit, See edit I have added a `pause` so you can see the message before it will exit with exit code `1`.